# Calling function from successful previous function

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm trying to properly execute a second stored procedure based on the success and output of the first one in a laravel file.

I'm currently executing this one successfully (Inserts record and returns the ID of the record in $out2 which is what I want)

```php
function firstRecord($firstName, $lastName, $email, $customer, $code, $auth)
{
    $stmt = \DB::connection()->getPdo()->prepare('CALL SCHEMA.INSERTRECORD(?,?,null,null,null,null,null,null,?,?,?,?)');

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $firstName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $lastName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $customer, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(5, $code, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(6, $out2, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);

    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Now when that one executes, I need to send some of the values (auth,out2 and email) into another function  that executes another procedure and all 4 params need to be strings:

```php
function secondRecord($out2, $email, $auth)
{
    $type = 'web';

    $userStmt = \DB::connection()->getPdo()->prepare('call SCHEMA.INSERTRECORDTWO(?,?,?,?)');

    $userStmt->bindParam(1, $out2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $userStmt->bindParam(2, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $userStmt->bindParam(3, $auth, PDO::PARAM_STR, 2500);
    $userStmt->bindParam(4, $type, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);

    $userStmt->execute();
}
```

How should I properly call the 2nd function with those values upon the success of the first procedure/function?

Comment: Before answering, I would like to know more about your use case of prepared statement. Laravel's ORM insert internally uses prepared statements. Why don't you use [laravel db insert](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#inserts) ? Are you inserting extremely large records at once ?

Comment: We are just using that as our convention going forward for stored procedures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your specific requirement of calling stored function, you can use below snippet :

Note that I am using named bindings which are cleaner to maintain. Also if your store procedure is returning(selecting) something,  they you can have that in as output using `DB::select()`.

I am deliberately catching the `QueryException` because if your database does no have the procedure to call or invalid params are passed, you can handle those in there

```
public function firstRecord($firstName, $lastName, $email, $customer, $code, $auth)
{
    try{

        $insertion = \DB::select( \DB::raw('CALL SCHEMA.INSERTRECORONE(:firstname, :lastname, null, null, null, null, null, null, :email, :customer, :code, :out2)', [

            'firstName' => $firstName,
            'lastName' => $lastName,
            'email' => $email,
            'customer' => $customer,
            'code' => $code,
            'out2' => $out2
        ]));

        $this->secondRecord($out2, $email, $auth, $insertion)
        return $insertion;
    }
    catch(QueryException $e){
        throw new \Exception('Unable to insert records : ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}

private function secondRecord($out2, $email, $auth, $insertion)
{
    try{

        $insertion = \DB::select( \DB::raw('CALL SCHEMA.INSERTRECORDTWO(:out2, :email, :auth, :type)', [

            'email' => $email,
            'auth' => $auth,
            'out2' => $out2,
            'type' = 'web'
        ]));

        return $insertion;
    }
    catch(QueryException $e){

        throw new \Exception('Unable to insert records in second function : ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

However, I will say laravel is pretty nice to do these things using eloquent models unless you have very specific reason to decrease the statement parsing time in MySQL and use stored function/procedure call.